# Audacious adding songs from SFTP drive

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sftp, 23.10, audacious

Is there some configuration needed to be able to add mp3 songs from a mounted SFTP drive into the Audacious music player?

If I start Audacious under Ubuntu's (23.10) Unity desktop I can take the Nautilus file manager, head over to the SFTP drive and pull the mp3 songs into the list of the Audacious window.
If I though do exactly the same thing under Ubuntu KDE using the Dolphin file manager, I will get this error:

[image]